# What are the possible values of the determinant of a permutation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

A permutation matrix $A$ is a nonsingular square matrix in which each row has exactly one entry = $1$, the other entries being all zeros. If $A$ is an $n×n$ permutation matrix, what are the possible values of determinant of $A$?

-------I think any such given matrix is a row column interchange operation of the Identity matrix.since change of row or column once change the sign only and the identity matrix has determinant $1$ so the answer will be $+1$ or $-1$.Am I right?
Does the logic is correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: You forgot to mention that also each column has exactly one entry equal to $1$, all other being zero. ;) As you stated it, you could put all the $1$s in a given column and get a determinant zero (if $n>1$).

Comment: @fkraiem, doesn't it say *non-singular* matrices?

Answer (score 2):

(Just so this question has an answer.)

As fkraiem points out, a permutation matrix is a matrix with precisely one $1$ in each row and precisely one $1$ in each column, and zeroes elsewhere.

Your argument is correct as is your conclusion. Furthermore, $n\times n$ permutation matrices are in one-to-one correspondence with $S_n$, the group of permutations on $n$ elements (hence the name). The determinant of a permutation matrix is the sign of the corresponding permutation.

Answer (score 1):

There's also another way of seeing it. If we develop the determinant with respect to the first row, we get the determinant of a permutation matrix of order $n-1$, with only possibly a change of sign. So, by induction on the order, we get that $\lvert\det A\rvert=1$.